# How does puppeter sharp get the value of an attribute?

Tags: c#, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

How does puppeter sharp get the value of an attribute?It seems that getting properties and controls is not as convenient as Windows Forms WebBrowser。
In the following code, I can't get the value of type

```
var node=await  page.QuerySelectorAsync("#uid" );
var vv=await node.GetPropertyAsync("type");
```

html

```
<input name="uid" type="text" style="height:50px;font-size:20px;" onkeypress="txtEnter(this,event)" class="form-control" id="uid">
```

Comment: Where is the C programming language? You need to have the correct tags

Comment: Doesn't look much like c code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `EvaluateFunctionAsync` is the most straight forward way to do this:

```cs
var type = await node.EvaluateFunctionAsync<string>("node => node.type");
```

Comment: i use document.getElementById("uid").getAttribute("type");